# How to prove this Lambert W integral representation?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, harmonic-functions, lambert-w

I was wondering how to prove this Lambert W identity.

$$ - \pi W(-1) = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{-1}{e}} \Im ( W ' (x) ) \ln(1 + \frac{1}{x} ) dx $$

Maybe with contour integration ??

Comment: $'$ means derivative ofcourse. And $Im$ imaginary part

Comment: I guess that the identity $W'(x)=\frac{W(x)}{x(1+W(x))}$ for the principal branch of the Lambert function and the substitution $x=te^t$ turn the integral into a simple one.

Comment: Also, integration by parts leads to the integral of the imaginary part of $\frac{W(x)}{x+x^2}$.

Comment: we are talking about the zeroth branch of $W$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio using a contour integration approach on your second proposed form of the integrand yields indeed the conjectured result (at least if one defines things much more accurate then op did)

Comment: @OP do you mean $W(-1+i\delta)$ or $W(-1-i\delta)$

Comment: How do we get rid of the imaginary part piece in the integrand ?

Comment: any reason why youa aren't answering my questions?

Comment: as this stands your original question is highly ill defined

Comment: Im talking about the standard definition of the Lambert W function ! How can a standard be confusing ? Any other interpretation makes the statement untrue anyways ?

Comment: do you know what a branch cut is?

Comment: Yes like the ln has a cut on the negative reals. That does not answer the OP. Im using standard def here , so im not sure what you are suggesting here. Post an answer or give a better hint.